# Codeigniter - Pagination with Search

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, pagination

I am doing a pagination with search function but everytime I click the pagination links in my page it does not work anymore. I think because form_validation is false now after you clicked page 2 or next.

Here is my code:

Controller: employee.php

```
public function search($start=0){
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('position', 'Position', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'trim');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->index();
    }
    else
    {
        if(($this->session->userdata('user_id')!="")&&($this->session->userdata('user_pos')=="administrator")){

            $config['base_url'] = base_url().'employee/search';
            $config['total_rows'] =$this->emp_model->getall_useraccounts();
            $config['per_page'] = 10; 
            $config['num_links'] = 4;
            $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
            $config['first_link'] = false;
            $config['last_link'] = false;
            $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

            $data['pages'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

            $this->load->model('emp_model');
            $data['search'] = $this->emp_model->search_2(10,$start);
            $data['view'] = $this->emp_model->get_posts();
            $this->load->view("include/header_admin.php");  
            $this->load->view("user_accounts_search.php",$data);
        }
        else{
            $this->index();
        }
    }


}
```

Models: emp_model.php

```
public function getall_useraccounts(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();

}
```

__

```
public function search_2($num,$start){

    $position=$this->input->post('position');
    $status=$this->input->post('status');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    if($position!='*'){
        $this->db->where('position',$position);
    }
    if($status!='*'){
        $this->db->where('status',$status);
    }
    $this->db->limit($num, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();


}
```

Views: user_accounts_search.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printDiv(divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">
                        City Environmental Management Office

                    </h1>
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="active">
                            <i class="fa fa-users"></i> Employees User Accounts
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>




            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body" style="overflow: scroll;">
                        <div id="printableArea">

                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                                <tr><?php echo form_open("employee/search"); ?>
                                    <th>PICTURE</th>
                                    <th>NAME</th>
                                    <th>USERNAME</th>
                                    <th>EMAIL</th>  
                                    <th><div><b>POSITION</b>
                                        <select name="position" class="form-control">

                                            <option value="*"><?php echo "ALL";?></option>
                                            <option value="administrator"><?php echo "Administartor";?></option>
                                            <option value="encoder"><?php echo "Encoder";?></option>
                                            <option value="enforcer"><?php echo "Enforcer";?></option>
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div></th>
                                    <th>STATUS
                                        <select name="status" class="form-control">

                                            <option value="*"><?php echo "ALL";?></option>
                                            <option value="1"><?php echo "Active";?></option>
                                            <option value="0"><?php echo "Deactive";?></option>

                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </th>   
                                    <th>ACTION <br>
                                    <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" /></th>
                                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                                        <?php 
                                        foreach($search as $viewview){
                                            $user_stats=$viewview['status'];
                                            $user_id=$viewview['user_id'];
                                            $image_name=$viewview['image_name'];
                                            if($user_stats=='0'){
                                                $color="danger";
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                $color="success";
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                            <tr class='<?php echo $color;?>'>
                                            <?php
                                            echo "<td>";
                                            if($image_name!=''){
                                            ?>
                                                <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/<?php echo $image_name;?>" alt="pic"  width="100" height="100">
                                            <?php
                                            }
                                            else{
                                            ?>
                                                <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>uploads/default.png" alt="pic" width="100" height="100">
                                            <?php
                                            }
                                            echo "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>".$viewview['lname'].", ".$viewview['fname']." ".$viewview['mname']."</td>";
                                            echo "<td>".$viewview['username']."</td>";  
                                            echo "<td>".$viewview['email']."</td>";
                                            echo "<td>".$viewview['position']."</td>";
                                            if($viewview['status']==0){
                                                echo "<td>"."DEACTIVE"."</td>";
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                echo "<td>"."ACTIVE"."</td>";
                                            }
                                            ?>  
                                            <td>
                                            <ul style="list-style: none;">
                                                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>employee/passwordupdateemp/<?php echo $user_id?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" role="button">CHANGE PASSWORD</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>employee/emailupdateemp/<?php echo $user_id?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" role="button">CHANGE EMAIL</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>employee/usernameupdateemp/<?php echo $user_id?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" role="button">CHANGE USERNAME</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>employee/update_emp_user/<?php echo $user_id?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">UPDATE</a></li>
                                                    <?php if($user_stats==0){?>
                                                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>employee/stat_activate/<?php echo $user_id?>" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" role="button">ACTIVATE</a></li>
                                                    <?php   
                                                    }
                                                    else if($user_stats==1){?>
                                                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>employee/stat_deactivate/<?php echo $user_id?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" role="button">DEACTIVATE</a></li>
                                                    <?php
                                                    }?>
                                            </ul>
                                            </td>
                                            <?php 
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                        }

                            ?>

                            </table>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <br>

                    </div>
                    <?php echo $pages;?>
                    <br>
                    <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="Print" class="btn btn-success"/>
<br>
                </div>
            </div>  
                </table>
        </div>  
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
```

thank you!

Comment: what display the $this->pagination->create_links(); link ?

Comment: @msvairam pagination links  **[1][2][3][>]**

Comment: I need link of pagination numbers

Comment: When you click on your pagination links, you are not submiting your search form through POST. 
The thing is, although your validation rules are not set to "required", if we check `system/library/Form_validation.php` we can see in the function `run()` that CodeIgniter is expecting to receive data.

   `// Do we even have any data to process?  Mm?`
    `$validation_array = empty($this->validation_data) ? $_POST : $this->validation_data;`
    `if (count($validation_array) === 0)
    {
     return FALSE;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Change this code

`$this->load->view("include/header_admin.php");
$this->load->view("user_accounts_search.php",$data);`

It should be

```
 $this->load->view("header_admin");
$this->load->view("user_accounts_search",$data);
```

Comment: When you get a chance, let me know if this http://superuser.com/questions/1028288/how-to-hide-window-os-folder-with-name/1028297#1028297 helped resolve your problem there that you had the question about...

Comment: I have wrote tutorial about Cdeigniter Pagination. Please have a look and give your suggestions https://www.cloudways.com/blog/pagination-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Thank you @OwaisAlam for this opportunity, How can i communicated with you ?

Comment: welcome you can communicate me @ owais.alam@cloudways.com